# Trying to insert 10000 records sqlite ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I am trying to insert 10000 records and its taking 45 secs

this is my code

```
println(NSDate.new())
for index in 0...10000{
countrys.insert(name <- "abc")
//println(index)
}
println(NSDate.new())
```

is this way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that SQLite will have to commit each of the `INSERT` statements individually. You should consider using transactions. You can start a transaction with `transaction` method (which performs `BEGIN TRANSACTION` SQL) and then use `commit` to commit them (which performs `COMMIT` SQL).

---

For example:

```
db.transaction(.Deferred) { txn in
    for i in 0 ... 10000 {
        if countries.insert(name <- "abc").statement.failed {
            return .Rollback
        }
    }

    return .Commit
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with some code, I am fairly new to iOS and swift.

Comment: Just FYI, I am trying to convert whole JSON to sqlite table, if you know a better way please let me know thanks @Rob

Comment: @vinbhai4u Glancing at this library, you'd either call `transaction` and `commit`, or judging from the API, it would appear you can call the `transaction` method with block parameter. See code snippets in my answer.

Comment: @vinbhai4u If the JSON is uniform (_i.e._, all objects have the same keys), you could try a bulk insert with a single statement, but you'd have to forgo the type-safe interface (till the library can provide such an interface itself), _e.g._, manually construct a statement and array of values: `"INSERT INTO table (c1, c2, c3) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)"`, etc.

Comment: There are tons of ways of doing it. See revised answer for just one example.